# What's the exact behavior of the promises?

Tags: javascript, angular, peerjs

I'm new to web development and I started facing promises recently, so in the code below the result gets resolved after a couple of milliseconds, but if I refresh my browser and I click the button right away I get an "undefined", so is it supposed to be like this or does the promise usually have to wait and not give any results(even undefined) unless it's resolved or failed or is my implementation wrong?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="showMyId()">Next</button>
  <h1>S {{myId}} </h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  thepeer: any;
  myId: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.thepeer = new Peer({key: '1h907r5xnvims4i'});
    this.showMyId();
  }

  showMyId(){
    this.getMyId().then((id)=>{
      this.myId = id;
      console.log(this.myId);
    })
  }

  getMyId(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      resolve(this.thepeer.id);
    })
  }



}
```

Your assistance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the `open` event to fire before you can use the ID:

```
getMyId(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.thepeer.on('open', (id) => {
          resolve(this.thepeer.id);
      });
   })
}
```

See the documentation: http://peerjs.com/docs/#start